# C#/Asp.net: Can we consume WCF Web Service with SqlDataReader?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, datatable, sqldatareader, sqldatatypes

Right now I'm currently converting WCF web service to `DataTable` (we know this can get messy), then planning to convert it to SQL Db Type. I was thinking, can't I just consume the WCF service as a SQL Db Type? If so, I've searched and couldn't find a solution to this. What I'm planning to do is sending the `DataTable` over Sql Data Type.

There exists this approach: http://sharpfellows.com/post/Returning-a-DataTable-over-SqlContextPipe. However, that's a 2006 article and I'd like to skip the .net `DataTable`.

Code example of how to read WCF as SQL datatype would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `DataReader` is a class that keep connection open with database, so you cannot consume a service that returns a `DataReader`.

And return a `DataTable` is equals a bad idea, you must read the data and return a class with just data.

Maybe a good solution to your scenario can be **WCF Data Services**, that do what you want: data access.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794(v=vs.110).aspx